Run Formatter (Black in Vscode) Path with whitespace
I have my files in a folder with a whitespace. /Volumes/USB SSD/....
If I run VScode Formatter (Black, autoflake) I get this Error:
Failed to run autoflake. Error: Stderr: /bin/sh: /Volumes/USB: No such file or directory
How can I fix this?
The host system is MacOs and the folder is on a external disk but I think the problem is just the whitespace.

ID and version number of your formatter extension please

Enclose your path in quotation marks like so:
"/Volumes/USB SSD/"

Yes but where can I do this for the vscode standard formatter?
